# Array doesn't work in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

[image]

This code works well. But if I change the code, it doesn't work.

[image]

I'd like anyone to help me if they has experience in Vue.js.

Comment: share code with code editor, not as image

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Error messages? Wrong output? Explosions? What is it supposed to do? What is the definition of `colorList`?

Comment: make your question clearer and dont use an image

Comment: Like other comments says you need to be more explicit. But My guess would be not to use `this.colorList[0]` but `colorList[0]`

Answer (score 0):

It does work, it should be used like this `{{colorList[0]}}` not `{{this.colorList[0]}}`since vue template is using the “Mustache” syntax.